# Задний фон приложения

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlabel, gif, qmovie

Делаю приложение на *PyQt5* и хочу поставить на задний фон приложения ролик или **`.gif`**, но ни как не могу найти информацию на счет этого.

Как это сделать?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class LoginForm(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(LoginForm, self).__init__(parent)

        # Create Login Window
        self.setWindowTitle("Авторизация")
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("ico.png"))
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint | Qt.MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint)
        self.setFixedSize(400, 500)

        
        # Background Login Window
        background = QPalette()
        background.setColor(QPalette.Background, QColor(236, 236, 236))
        self.setPalette(background)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        frame = QFrame(self)
        frame.setFrameShape(QFrame.NoFrame)
        frame.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Sunken)
        frame.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        frame.setFixedWidth(400)
        frame.setFixedHeight(80)
        frame.move(0, 0)
  
        Title = QFont()
        Title.setPointSize(16)
        Title.setBold(True)
    
        labelUser = QLabel("пользователь", self)
        labelUser.move(60, 39)

        frameUser = QFrame(self)
        frameUser.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        frameUser.setFixedWidth(280)
        frameUser.setFixedHeight(28)
        frameUser.move(60, 60)

        imageUser = QLabel(frameUser)
        imageUser.setPixmap(QPixmap("User.png").scaled(20, 20, Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.SmoothTransformation))
        imageUser.move(10, 4)
        self.lineEditUser = QLineEdit(frameUser)
        self.lineEditUser.setFrame(False)
        self.lineEditUser.setTextMargins(8, 0, 4, 1)
        self.lineEditUser.setFixedWidth(238)
        self.lineEditUser.setFixedHeight(26)
        self.lineEditUser.move(40, 1)


        labelPassword = QLabel("пароль", self)
        labelPassword.move(60, 89)

        framePassword = QFrame(self)
        framePassword.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        framePassword.setFixedWidth(280)
        framePassword.setFixedHeight(28)
        framePassword.move(60, 110)

        imagenPassword = QLabel(framePassword)
        imagenPassword.setPixmap(QPixmap("Password.png").scaled(20, 20, Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.SmoothTransformation))
        imagenPassword.move(10, 4)

        self.lineEditPassword = QLineEdit(framePassword)
        self.lineEditPassword.setFrame(False)
        self.lineEditPassword.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)
        self.lineEditPassword.setTextMargins(8, 0, 4, 1)
        self.lineEditPassword.setFixedWidth(238)
        self.lineEditPassword.setFixedHeight(26)
        self.lineEditPassword.move(40, 1)

        buttonLogin = QPushButton("ВОЙТИ", self)
        buttonLogin.setFixedWidth(135)
        buttonLogin.setFixedHeight(28)
        buttonLogin.move(60, 150)
        buttonLogout = QPushButton("ВЫЙТИ", self)
        buttonLogout.setStyleSheet("background-color: black")
        buttonLogout.setFixedWidth(135)
        buttonLogout.setFixedHeight(28)
        buttonLogout.move(205, 150)

        labelInformacion = QLabel("<a href='#'>Нет аккаунта? Зарегистрироваться</a>.", self)
        labelInformacion.setOpenExternalLinks(True)
        labelInformacion.setToolTip("More information")
        labelInformacion.move(115, 480)


if __name__ == '__main__':      
    aplicacion = QApplication(sys.argv)
    aplicacion.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Century Gothic", 12))
    Window = LoginForm()
    Window.show()
    sys.exit(aplicacion.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class LoginForm(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(LoginForm, self).__init__(parent)

        # Create Login Window
        self.setWindowTitle("Авторизация")
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("im.png"))
        
        
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint | Qt.MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint)
        self.setFixedSize(400, 500)
        
        # Background Login Window
        background = QPalette()
# +++ -->                                                         -->  v
        background.setColor(QPalette.Background, QColor(236, 136, 136, 0))
        self.setPalette(background)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        frame = QFrame(self)
        frame.setFrameShape(QFrame.NoFrame)
        frame.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Sunken)
        frame.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        frame.setFixedWidth(400)
        frame.setFixedHeight(80)
        frame.move(0, 0)
  
        Title = QFont()
        Title.setPointSize(16)
        Title.setBold(True)
    
        labelUser = QLabel("пользователь", self)
        labelUser.move(60, 39)

        frameUser = QFrame(self)
        frameUser.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        frameUser.setFixedWidth(280)
        frameUser.setFixedHeight(28)
        frameUser.move(60, 60)

        imageUser = QLabel(frameUser)
        imageUser.setPixmap(QPixmap("lena-2.png").scaled(
            20, 20, Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.SmoothTransformation))
        imageUser.move(10, 4)
        self.lineEditUser = QLineEdit(frameUser)
        self.lineEditUser.setFrame(False)
        self.lineEditUser.setTextMargins(8, 0, 4, 1)
        self.lineEditUser.setFixedWidth(238)
        self.lineEditUser.setFixedHeight(26)
        self.lineEditUser.move(40, 1)

        labelPassword = QLabel("пароль", self)
        labelPassword.move(60, 89)

        framePassword = QFrame(self)
        framePassword.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        framePassword.setFixedWidth(280)
        framePassword.setFixedHeight(28)
        framePassword.move(60, 110)

        imagenPassword = QLabel(framePassword)
        imagenPassword.setPixmap(QPixmap("Ok.png").scaled(
            20, 20, Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.SmoothTransformation))
        imagenPassword.move(10, 4)

        self.lineEditPassword = QLineEdit(framePassword)
        self.lineEditPassword.setFrame(False)
        self.lineEditPassword.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)
        self.lineEditPassword.setTextMargins(8, 0, 4, 1)
        self.lineEditPassword.setFixedWidth(238)
        self.lineEditPassword.setFixedHeight(26)
        self.lineEditPassword.move(40, 1)

        buttonLogin = QPushButton("ВОЙТИ", self)
        buttonLogin.setFixedWidth(135)
        buttonLogin.setFixedHeight(28)
        buttonLogin.move(60, 150)
        buttonLogout = QPushButton("ВЫЙТИ", self)
        buttonLogout.setStyleSheet("background-color: black; color: red")
        buttonLogout.setFixedWidth(135)
        buttonLogout.setFixedHeight(28)
        buttonLogout.move(205, 150)

        labelInformacion = QLabel(
            "<a href='#'>Нет аккаунта? Зарегистрироваться</a>.", self)
        labelInformacion.setOpenExternalLinks(True)
        labelInformacion.setToolTip("More information")
        labelInformacion.move(115, 410)


class GifImg(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    def __init__(self, file_name, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.move = QtGui.QMovie(file_name)
        self.move.start()
        self.setMovie(self.move)
        self.setScaledContents(True)


class Main(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        label_gif = GifImg("Animhorse.gif")               # установите свою .gif
        label_gif.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter) 

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(label_gif)
   
        self.loginForm = LoginForm(label_gif)
        self.loginForm.move(0, 0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Main()
    w.resize(450, 450)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]